# React native navigation drawer is not covering header in my application

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I am new to react native development, but i have some requirement with react navigation drawer. I want to display the navigation drawer from top of the screen but it is display below from toolbar. It is a combination of both Stack and Drawer screens. Following is my code in App.js

```
function App() {
  SplashScreen.hide()
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {/* headerMode='float' */}
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Login' >
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        {/* <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} /> */}
        <Stack.Screen name="DrawerScreens" component={DrawerScreens} 
          options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
            title: "Home",
            headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF', headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#154493'},
            headerLeft: props => <NavigationDrawerStructure navObj={navigation} />,
          })} />

        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} 
            options={({ route }) => ({headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF', headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#154493'}})} />
</Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

DrawerScreens function is like following..

```
function DrawerScreens({ route, navigation }) {
  // console.log("param:"+route.params.token)
  return (
    //drawerContent={props=>CustomDrawerContent(props)}
    // <SafeAreaProvider>

    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => CustomDrawerContent(props)} headerMode="float" >
    {/* <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => CustomDrawerContent(props)}> */}
      {/* options={{ drawerLabel: 'Updates' }} */}

      <Drawer.Screen name="LandingScreen" component={LandingScreen}
        initialParams={{ token: route.params.token }}/>
  );
}
```

CustomDrawer function contains list of the menu items which is dynamic and NestedMenuView is taking care of that..

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
 <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}} forceInset={{ top: "always" }}>

      <NestedMenuView navObj={props.navigation} />

      </SafeAreaView>       

  );
};
```

[image: Please check the reference image here, I want left menu starts from header instead of below from header]

For me the combination of both stack and drawer screens.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything in you're code, but if this can help, I make drawer with react navigation v5, you can check the code : https://github.com/samuel3105/react-native-navigation

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem lies around the Stack Navigator or the Screen components;

If you use the latest, after v5 release version of @react-navigation/drawer (mine is 5.6.3) the recommended way is to use the built-in wrappers when creating custom drawer

```js
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const Menu = (props) => {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem label="Help" onPress={() => {}} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
};

export default function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Tabs"
      drawerContent={(props) => <Menu {...props} />}
      edgeWidth={100}
      drawerContentOptions={{
        activeTintColor: Colors.accentColor,
        labelStyle: {
          fontFamily: 'open-sans',
        },
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen...
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
```

You can also leave the scrollview and create custom ui like this:

```js
const contentOptions = {
    activeBackgroundColor: '#dbdbdb',
    activeLabelStyle: {
        fontSize: 16,
        color: 'black',
        fontFamily: 'roboto'
    },
    labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        color: intenseGrey,
        fontFamily: 'roboto'
    }
};

    return (
        <View
            style={{
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                flexGrow: 1
            }}
        >
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, paddingBottom: 0 }}>
                <View style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#dbdbdb',
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    flexGrow: 1}}
                 >
                    <View>
                        <DrawerItemList {...props} {...contentOptions} />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
    );
```

Comment: Thanks MR.Bence Rozsa for giving quick response. If i have single level list then the above solution will work i guess. But i want the menu list will be multi level means when i click on the item it opens other list inside it upto 2 levels. So that purpose i used 'NestedMenuView'..Can you please look in such a way and let me know if you have any other..

Comment: Sure, I understand now. I haven't done multi-level drawer navigation, although  @gie3d is surely right about using drawer on the top, and nest everything below that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that Drawer is not covering is because you put the Drawer navigation inside your Stack navigation.

Yours

```
Stack
   Drawer
```

To fixed that you have to readjust the order

```
Drawer
    Stack
```

For example (or you could see from my snack here: https://snack.expo.io/@gie3d/d25aca)

```js
const HomeStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={({navigation}) => ({
      title: "Home",
      headerLeft: () => (
          <Ionicons
            name={'md-menu'}
            size={24}
            style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
            onPress={() =>
              navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())
            }
          />
        ),
    })} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

const Home = () => {
  return (
  <View>
    <Text>This is Home</Text>
  </View>
)}

export default () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeStack">
        <Drawer.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStack} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="HomeNoStack" component={Home} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response MR.gie3d. I used your technique with two of the screens login,landing screens but showing navigation drawer in login screen too. How can i avoid that to display with login screen.please help me out..

Comment: updated the code in app.js is <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Login" >
        <Drawer.Screen name="LandingScreen" component={LandingScreen}/>

        {/* <Drawer.Screen name="DrawerScreens" component={DrawerScreens} /> */}
        
        <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}
          navigationOptions={{
            gesturesEnabled: false,
          }}
          options={{ headerShown: false, gesturesEnabled: false }} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow. The idea is to have separate Navigators for Login and other After Login.

Comment: Not sure, but i want it to be work like following.1.Loginscreen doesn't show navigation drawer 2. Once i login i need it should show from top of the screen.

Comment: I need the combination of both screens even after login @gie3d.

Comment: Yes, you can see how to implement from the link i sent you above (auth flow)

Comment: How can i mention both stack and drawer screens in app.js after login??

Answer (score 0):

The following stacks created and calling these stacks from Drawer Screens.

```
const LandingStack = ({ route, navigation }) => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="LandingScreen" component={LandingScreen} options={({navigation}) => ({
      headerTitle: 'Home',
      headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF', headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#000' },
      headerLeft: props => <NavigationDrawerStructure navObj={navigation} />,
    })} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

const TicketingStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="TicketingDashboard" component={TicketingDashboard} options={({route, navigation}) => ({
      headerTitle: route.params.type,
      headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF', headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#000' },
      headerLeft: props => <NavigationDrawerStructure navObj={navigation} />,
    })} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);


function DrawerScreens({ route, navigation }) {
  // console.log("param:"+route.params.token)
  return (
    //drawerContent={props=>CustomDrawerContent(props)}
    <SafeAreaProvider>

    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => CustomDrawerContent(props)} headerMode="screen">


      {/* options={{ drawerLabel: 'Updates' }} */}

      {/* <Stack.Screen name="DrawerScreens" component={DrawerScreens}
          options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
            title: "Home",
            headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF', headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#000' },
            headerLeft: props => <NavigationDrawerStructure navObj={navigation} />,
          })} /> */}

      <Drawer.Screen name="LandingStack" component={LandingStack}

        initialParams={{ token: route.params.token }}/>

      <Drawer.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStack}
        initialParams={{ token: route.params.token }} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>

    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

And I have removed header part from the function App and finally looks like this in the App.js

```
 <Stack.Screen name="DrawerScreens" component={DrawerScreens}
          options={{ headerShown: false }} />
```

Comment: My answer helps to someone who are using same architecture and facing the same issue.Thanks everyone for giving the inputs to solve the issue.